# How to anti-aliased zoom on screen recordings?

Tags: screen, desktop-recording

I am wondering how Google is making these screencast/screen recordings, that are very high resolution when the zoom in.

Like this one:
[Dear Sophie](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4vkVHijdQk)

Like when you use camtasia or Screenflow it gets all fuzzy when you zoom in on an area, and it does not look very good.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are most likely remaking all their interfaces in flash (which is vector graphics, so everything will look smooth... except that youtube video haha) as it's google's style to do such a thing. So no, it's not possible to do this sort of thing using conventional methods.